# Duplicate efficiently documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, performance, copy

I would like to find-out the **most efficient way to duplicate documents in MongoDB**, given that I want to take a bunch of documents from an existing collection, update one of their field, unset _id to generate a new one, and push them back in the collection to create duplicates.

This is typically to create a **"branching" feature** in MongoDB, allowing users to modify data in two separate branches at the same time.

I've tried the following things:

1. In my server, get data chunks in multiple threads, modify data, and insert modified data with a new _id in the base

This basically works but performance is not super good (~ 20s for 1 million elements).

2. In the future MongoDB version (tested on version 4.1.10), use [the new $out aggregation mechanism](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) to insert in the same collection

This does not seem to work and raise an error message `"errmsg" : "$out with mode  insertDocuments is not supported when the output collection is the same as the aggregation collection"`

Any ideas how to be faster than the first approach? Thanks!

Comment: `$out` does seem like the closest tool to what you want -- one hacky approach could be to use two different aggregations -- one to copy into a separate collection, and a separate to copy back into the original collection.

Comment: Thanks @willis, I'm a bit disappointed MongoDB cannot do such a thing in a single query though...